# Why can't I change check marks and up/down arrows?

Tags: support

I am new to Ask Ubuntu. I asked a question and got a prompt and useful answer. I wanted to thank the responder and click his up arrow, but discovered I had to be registered to do it, and that it required me to have an OpenID.
I got an OpenID through my Yahoo account; Yahoo said just type in yahoo.com when a site asked for my OpenID. I clicked the Ask Ubuntu register button, put in yahoo.com, went to yahoo and signed in, and it then sent me back to Ask Ubuntu. I thought I was all set, but I am still unable to make any comments, or change the arrows and check mark.
Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Your "unregistered" account and your "registered" account need to be merged.

Answer (score 5):

Your "unregistered" account and your "registered" account need to be merged.

(I don't know why Marco Ceppi gives this answer as a comment, preventing you from accepting an answer.) :)